# Is there a way to avoid falcon doubling the memory needed in Python?

Tags: python, memory, falconframework

I'm somewhat of a novice on Python, though have a solid understanding of other programming languages.  We have a set of code that's using python but amounts to this.

```
  def on_get(self, req, resp):

      try:

         proc = Popen(["createLotsofData","-p"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
         out_str, err_str = proc.communicate()

         if err_str:
            handle_error(req, resp, "{0} returned '{1}'".format(program, err_str))
            return

         if not out_str:
            handle_error(req, resp, "{0} returned empty file".format(program))
            return

         resp.body = out_str

         resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

      except Exception as e:
         handle_error(req, resp, "Caught exception " + repr(e))
         return
```

Essentially we have a program that can output large amounts of log information.  We're talking upwards of 600 megs or more.

Problem is if our system has 900 megs of Ram (or really anything under 1.2-1.3 gigs) This throws a MemoryError.   So after trying out the code, I find that when I out_str is a 600 meg string, and then we call resp.body = out_str appears to duplicate this memory.   This is not good.

I've tried a version where I piped the output of the Popen to a file and then tried to use that, though moving it to a file seemed to require a similar amount of memory as the stdout=PIPE method.

I've tried an alternate version using the stream nature of stdout such as

```
     try:
         proc = Popen(["createLotsofData","-p"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

         resp.content_type = "text/csv"
         resp.stream = proc.stdout
         resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

      except Exception as e:
         handle_error(req, resp, "Caught exception " + repr(e))
         return
```

but even in this case we still see a MemoryError.

So I believe I understand what's happening in the first case, resp.body and out_str need unique copies of the data, so that blows our memory limit.  But why is it also happening with the second example? And is there a way to avoid seeing python balloon up and need 2x times my output size?

Comment: Why the `except Exception:` and empty return statements?